# Creating SearchBox in listView

Tags: android, listview, android-studio, android-fragments

I have created a "Search" box in Android. When I try to search for anything it is not showing the updated value in the list. The value is coming in to the list but the search related value is not changing. Here is my Snapshot:

[image: this is my search box Image]

If I enter "ab" it's working fine, but when I am putting "s", it's showing the first listView item like this:

[image: Image 2]

Here is my Fragment class where I am using `addTextChangeListener`:

```
etSearchUser.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            if (i2<i1){
                adapter.resetData();
            }
            adapter.getFilter().filter(charSequence);
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Here is my Adapter Class:

```
public class RemoveUserAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private ArrayList<UserModel> listcontent;
private ArrayList<UserModel> searchList;
Context context;
private Filter planetFilter;
UserModel content, content1;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public RemoveUserAdapter(Context context, ArrayList listContent) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listcontent = listContent;
    this.searchList = listContent;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return listcontent.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {

    return listcontent.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return listcontent.get(i).hashCode();
}


class ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvEmail, tvUserId;
    private CheckBox checkBox;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder, viewHolder1;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remove_user_adapter, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvEmail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailUser);
        viewHolder.tvUserId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvUserGroup);
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        viewHolder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }


    content = (UserModel) listcontent.get(i);
    content = (UserModel) searchList.get(i);
    //Log.i("@@@",content.getEmail()+" email");
    viewHolder.tvEmail.setText(content.getEmail());
    viewHolder.tvUserId.setText(content.getUsergroup());
    return view;
}

public void resetData() {
    listcontent = searchList;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults result) {
            listcontent = (ArrayList<UserModel>) result.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<UserModel> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<UserModel>();
            if (searchList == null) {
                searchList = new ArrayList<UserModel>(listcontent);
            }
            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                // set the Original result to return
                results.count = searchList.size();
                results.values = searchList;
            } else {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (int i = 0; i < searchList.size(); i++) {
                    content = (UserModel) searchList.get(i);
                    String data = content.getEmail();
                    String user = content.getUserId();
                    if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                        FilteredArrList.add(new UserModel(data, user));
                    }
                }
                results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrList;
            }
            return results;
        }

    };
    return filter;
}
```

}

For search I am using a simple EditText.

And one more thing is it's searching from the very first letter of Gmail.
I want to make it search randomly.

For example: `abc@gmail.com` is there, if I enter in the search box "gmail" it should show a result.

Here is my UserModel Class:

```
public class UserModel {
private String usergroup;
private String name;
private String email;
private String phone;
private String password;
private String userId;

public UserModel(String email, String userGroup) {
    super();
    this.email = email;
    this.usergroup = userGroup;
}
public UserModel(){}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getUsergroup() {
    return usergroup;
}

public void setUsergroup(String usergroup) {
    this.usergroup = usergroup;
}

public String getPhone() {
    return phone;
}

public void setPhone(String phone) {
    this.phone = phone;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
```

}

Comment: replace your data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString()) with data.toLowerCase().contains(constraint.toString())

Answer (score 1):

In `getCount` you must return filtered list count not original list count.
See this gist for more information:
https://gist.github.com/fjfish/3024308

I update your code:

```
public class RemoveUserAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {
private ArrayList<UserModel> listcontent;
private ArrayList<UserModel> searchList;
Context context;
private Filter planetFilter;
UserModel content, content1;
LayoutInflater inflater;

public RemoveUserAdapter(Context context, ArrayList listContent) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listcontent = listContent;
    this.searchList = listContent;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return searchList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {

    return searchList.get(i);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return searchList.get(i).hashCode();
}


class ViewHolder {
    private TextView tvEmail, tvUserId;
    private CheckBox checkBox;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    final ViewHolder viewHolder, viewHolder1;
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.remove_user_adapter, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.tvEmail = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvEmailUser);
        viewHolder.tvUserId = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvUserGroup);
        viewHolder.checkBox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        viewHolder.checkBox.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);

    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
    }


    content = (UserModel) getItem(i);
    viewHolder.tvEmail.setText(content.getEmail());
    viewHolder.tvUserId.setText(content.getUsergroup());
    return view;
}

public void resetData() {
    searchList=listcontent;
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    Filter filter = new Filter() {

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence charSequence, FilterResults result) {
            searchList = (ArrayList<UserModel>) result.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
            ArrayList<UserModel> FilteredArrList = new ArrayList<UserModel>();

            if (constraint == null || constraint.length() == 0) {

                // set the Original result to return
                results.count = listcontent.size();
                results.values = listcontent;
            } else {
                constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
                for (int i = 0; i < listcontent.size(); i++) {
                    content = (UserModel) listcontent.get(i);
                    String data = content.getEmail();
                    String user = content.getUserId();
                    if (data.toLowerCase().startsWith(constraint.toString())) {
                        FilteredArrList.add(content);
                    }
                }
                results.count = FilteredArrList.size();
                results.values = FilteredArrList;
            }
            return results;
        }

    };
    return filter;
}
```

Comment: u saved my time

Comment: @Abhay don't up vote! If answer is correct, just accept it by click on the check mark on left side of my answer. :)